# Git: How to open my local branch's pull request URL?

Tags: git

I was watching this video: https://youtu.be/9qsX_UsyG-g?t=30

And I noticed that he/she had a custom command to open his branch's pull request using `propen`

I want to implement this myself. How would I get my branch's URL so I can open it using `open "www.github.com/..."`

Answer (score 0):

This is [computed by GitHub](https://github.blog/changelog/2018-09-10-pull-request-url-output-in-the-command-line/) and similar automatically only when pushing a new branch to your remote:

```sh
$ git checkout -b test/new origin/master 
Branch 'test/new' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'test/new'
✘-128 ~/source/packer [test/new|✔] 
$ git push -u origin test/new
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: Create a pull request for 'test/new' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/zaventh/packer/pull/new/test/new
remote: 
To https://github.com/zaventh/packer.git
 * [new branch]          test/new -> test/new
Branch 'test/new' set up to track remote branch 'test/new' from 'origin'.
```

You'll notice the `remote:` prefix to those messages. The text is actually coming from GitHub in this case and not the client. Presumably they are using a `post-receive` [server side Git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to accomplish this.